# How to alternate case in a provided string using a for loop

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to create a for loop that will alternate upper and lowercase letters in a provided string (given as user input). 
My general idea is to make a for loop starting at 0 and ending at the length of the string, with a step size of 2. 
This is what I have so far (x is the string variable).

```
for a in range (0,len(x),2):
    x=x[0:a] + x[a].upper + x[a+1::]
    print("Alternate Lowercase Letters:", a)
```

When I use this, I get an error message that says

> "TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two things that jump out- 1) you need parentheses for a function call (`.upper()`) and 2) you're printing `a` when you should be printing `x`. Change it to `x=x[0:a] + x[a].upper() + x[a+1::]` and `print("....", x)` and you should be good.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned earlier, the cause of that error is that you have `x[a].upper` instead of `x[a].upper()`. So Python thinks you want to concatenate that method with the `x[0:a]` and `x[a+1::]` strings, and that doesn't make sense.

However, there are better ways to do this task. You can use a list comprehension to perform the case-changing and then use the `.join` method to convert the list contents into a string. Here are two variations.

We can use `enumerate` to get the character index while we iterate over the characters in the input string. If the index is odd, we make the char lower-case, otherwise we make it upper-case.

```
def alt_case(s):
    return ''.join([u.lower() if i % 2 else u.upper() for i, u in enumerate(s)])
```

Alternatively, we can use slicing to separate the odd & even chars, and then use zip to put them back together after performing the case transformations.

```
def alt_case(s):
    hi = s[::2].upper()
    lo = s[1::2].lower()
    return ''.join([u+v for u, v in zip(hi, lo)])
```

Here's code that tests those functions.

```
s = 'This is a test'
print(alt_case(s))
```

**output**

```
ThIs iS A TeSt
```

---

FWIW, here's a cryptic variant of the first version:

```
def alt_case(s):
    return ''.join([(str.upper, str.lower)[i%2](u) for i, u in enumerate(s)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, as pault mentioned, is that you use `.upper` rather than `.upper()`. The former gives you a function reference, and the latter gives you the return value of the function.

Another thing to consider, if the string `x` is long, is to cast it to a list and reassign values rather than reconstructing the whole string every iteration. If `x` is a short string, it doesn't really matter as there will be no perceivable runtime difference, but if it is rather long, there would certainly be a significant difference in runtime since this method is O(x) while your current method is O(x<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: That's one problem. The other problem is that OP is printing `a` (the index variable) and not `x` (the string).

Comment: True, though I wasn't sure if that was on purpose, just for debugging, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `generater-comprehension` with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). I believe that this is the most efficient solution:

```
def alternate(s):
    return ''.join(c.upper() if i & 1 else c.lower() for i, c in enumerate(s))
```

and a test shows it works:

```
>>> alternate('testing')
'tEsTiNg'
```

Comment: Alternatively `if i%2 == 0`, which may be easier than bitwise operations for beginners to understand.

Comment: `''.join((str.upper if i%2 else str.lower)(c) for i,c in enumerate(text))` :)

Comment: @DYZ I like it.